# Spark SQL: register a DataFrame as a table using registerTempTable()

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using the `registerTempTable()` method to register the DataFrame df as a table named of my dataset.

Then, I ran the `SQLContext` method tableNames to return the list of tables.

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlCtx.read.json("dataset.json")
df.registerTempTable('dataset')
tables = sqlCtx.tableNames()
print(tables)
```

I got this error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'registerTempTable'

Can you please help to solve it. Thank you.

Comment: May I know which version of Spark you’re using?

Comment: hello, I am using version 3.0.0-preview

Answer (score 6):

This function is deprecated since 2.0.0 `registerTempTable(tableName:String)`.

You should use `createOrReplaceTempView()` instead.

> **Note**:: Deprecated in 2.0, use createOrReplaceTempView instead

Check Spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame.registerTempTable).

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me

```
import findspark
import pyspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlCtx.read.json("dataset.json")
df.registerTempTable('dataset')
tables = sqlCtx.tableNames()
print(tables)
```